# How to correctly use the JavaScriptStringEncode() method?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I want someone to inform me, how to implement   `JavaScriptStringEncode()`   function and what is used for ?

Comment: Please be a little more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do like this

```
<script>
   // wrap in quotes automatically
   alert(<%=HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(MyStringHere, true)%>);
   // add quotes manually
   alert("<%=HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(MyStringHere)%>");
   alert("<%=HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(MyStringHere, false)%>");
</script>
```

HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode() Method will convert html content to javascript compatible.

Answer (score 0):

"This method encodes strings. For instance, single quotation marks and double quotation marks are included as \' and \" in the encoded string.

URL encoding makes sure that all browsers correctly transmit text in URL strings. Characters such as a question mark (?), ampersand (&), slash (/), and spaces might be truncated or corrupted by some browsers. Therefore, these characters must be encoded in a elements or in query strings where the strings can be re-sent by a browser in a request string."

For more info [enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd991914%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)